# Ensuring that an async task has fully cancelled before restarting that task

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task

OK, here goes: I have a part of an application where I am querying rows from a database. I perform the query when the user enters text into a search box (or alters another filter setting).

The data that is returned from the database is going into an ObservableCollection which is bound to a DataGrid. Because I'm conscious of keeping the UI responsive, I'm using Async-Await to (attempt) to fill this ObservableCollection in the background.

So, in my mind, every time the user types something (or changes the filter settings) I want to cancel the ongoing task *wait for it to confirm it's cancelled* and then "restart" (or rather create a new task) with the new settings.

But I'm getting all sorts of weird results (especially when I slow down the task to simulate slow database access) such as the collection not getting cleared and being populated twice and when disposing the CancellationTokenSource (which I read is a good idea) sometimes when I get to the point of calling `Cancel()` it's been disposed in the meantime and I get an exception.

I suspect that the issue stems from a fundamental gap in my understanding of the pattern I'm meant to use here so any style/pattern pointers are as welcome as an actual technical solution.

The code basically goes like this:

```
ObservableCollection<Thing> _thingCollection;
Task _thingUpdaterTask;
CancellationTokenSource _thingUpdaterCancellationSource;

// initialisation etc. here

async void PopulateThings(ThingFilterSettings settings)
{
     // try to cancel any ongoing task
     if(_thingUpdaterTask?.IsCompleted ?? false){
         _thingUpdaterCancellationSource.Cancel();
         await _thingUpdaterTask;
     }

     // I'm hoping that any ongoing task is now done with, 
     // but in reality that isn't happening. I'm guessing
     // that's because Tasks are getting dereferenced and 
     // orphaned in concurrent calls to this method?

     _thingCollection.Clear();
     _thingUpdaterCancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
     var cancellationToken = _thingUpdaterCancellationSource.Token;
     var progressHandler = new Progress<Thing>(x => _thingCollection.add(x));
     var progress = (IProgress<Thing>)progressHandler;

     try{
         _thingUpdaterTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => GetThings(settings, progress, cancellationToken));
         await _thingUpdaterTask; 
     }catch(AggregateException e){
         //handle stuff etc.
     }finally{
         // should I be disposing the Token Source here?
     }
}

void GetThings(ThingFilterSettings settings, 
               IProgress<Thing> progress, 
               CancellationToken ctok){
    foreach(var thingy in SomeGetThingsMethod(settings)){
        if(ctok.IsCancellationRequested){
            break;
        }
        progress.Report(thingy);
    }
}
```

Comment: `await` unwraps exceptions, no need to catch `AggregateException`.

Comment: @dymanoid - i made a typo when trying to generalise my code for the example. Fixed and hopefully making sense now!

Comment: @LexyStardust do not use `async void` except for event handlers. You should update that method to return `Task`

Comment: Your "void GetThings(...)" should minimally be "Task GetThings(...)" otherwise it is a "fire-and-forget" method and the await within your if will always return immediately. For the rest it seems OK to me.

Comment: OK, I've updated "GetThings" to be `async Task` (although Visual Studio is now warning me that there's nothing awaited in there - is that OK?). This change hasn't actually made any difference to the issue though unfortunately (in both areas - the collection being filled multiple times without being cleared and getting ObjectDisposedException if I put the dispose of the Token Source back in)...

Answer (score 0):

You could add a wrapper class, that will wait for the previous task execution to stop (either by finishing or by canceling) before starting the new task.

```
public class ChainableTask
{
    private readonly Task _task;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public ChainableTask(Func<CancellationToken, Task> asyncAction,
                        ChainableTask previous = null)
    {
        _task = Execute(asyncAction, previous);
    }

    private async Task CancelAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            _cts.Cancel();
            await _task;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        { }
    }

    private async Task Execute(Func<CancellationToken, Task> asyncAction, ChainableTask previous)
    {
        if (previous != null)
            await previous.CancelAsync();

        if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;

        await asyncAction(_cts.Token);
    }
}
```

If used the class above in previous projects. The class takes a lambda, the `asyncAction` to create the next task. The task is only created after the previous has finished.

It will pass a `CancellationToken` to each task, to allow the task to stop before finishing. Before the starting the next task, the token of the previous is canceled and the previous task is awaited. This happens in `CancelAsync`.

Only after the previous `Cancel` was awaited, we call the lambda to create the next task.

A usage example:

```
var firstAction = new ChainableTask(async tcs => await Task.Delay(1000));
var secondAction = new ChainableTask(async tcs => await Task.Delay(1000), firstAction ); // pass the previous action
```

In this example, the created task does not support cancellation, so the second call to `ChainableTask` will wait until the first `Task.Delay(1000)` finishes, before calling the second.